# How to make small change to large text file in PHP without having to deal with the whole file?

Tags: php, text, text-files

I am working with very large text files in php (up to 10gb in size), how can i make a small change in the file(like removing or adding a line) without having to read and write the whole file to disk each time?

what i mean is, i want to make a direct change to a small piece of the file without having to deal with the whole file...

Comment: What are these flat files you are dealing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) which will create a resource to your file.  Then manipulate the resource with [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to where you want to read/write and then [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) and [`fputs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php) for what you want to do to that portion of the file.

This will only work for altering and appending data.  If you want to remove data from the file, then you'll have to rewrite the entire file from the point you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the length of the file then there's no way to avoid rewriting the portion of the file from the position of the change to the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with text files, you can't replace a "line" in the middle of the file, because it's a stream of characters.  Unless you're making one-for-one character replacements, you'll have to rewrite the entire file.

However, you could probably use a better tool for the task, such as Perl or some of the Unix command line utilities.  What are you actually trying to do with these large text files?

Answer (score -4):

This question is a little vague. typically in php you just highlite the part you want to delete and hit backspace, then you can edit it how you want. Usually you can hit F3 or CTRL + F to search for a bit that you need to edit. Also, 10g? Im curious what this even does.

Comment: Oh come on, if youre going to downvote me at least tell me why.

Comment: The question is asking about how to open a file with PHP and edit its contents within the language.  Not about opening the file in an external editor.

Comment: At least explain to me why a file is 10g.

Comment: I don't see why a file can't be 10GB in size. And I can think of a few use cases like log files or database exports.

Comment: i just dont find it believable

Comment: Thanks for asking, for learning purposes I am creating a small/simple sql language storing data within textfiles, currently the script loads the entire file, makes a change, then writes the file content back to disk, however, this implies a serious speed and resource issue when dealing with large files, therefore I am looking for a better way to alter small parts of the file without having to rewrite the entire file... but as i read, it seams that is the only option :)

Comment: @DanielVallandTorgrimsen this is not true, you can do it, look at the answer from afuzzyllama